# Initialize a Many-To-Many relationship in Symfony3/Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

**Edited: Many to Many relationship instead of One To Many**

Given entities: **User** & **Item**.

**Item** has a boolean property named: **$mandatory**.

**User** is related to *Many-To-Many* **Items**.

At the creation/construction of a new **User**, he must be related (initialization) *to every* **Item** that has ($mandatory) property set to true.

What is the best practice to ensure these requirements in Symfony3/Doctrine2 ?

Comment: Are you sure its OTM relation not MTM ?

Comment: **Edited: Many to Many relationship instead of One To Many**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to this solution, inspired by @kunicmarko20 's hint above.

I had to subscribe to the *preFlush*() event, then, use the *UnitOfWork* object through the *PreFlushEventArgs*  argument to get the entities scheduled for insertion.

If I encounter a *User* instance of such entities, I just add all *mandatory* items to it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/UserInitializerSubscriber.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs ;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Item;


class UserInitializerSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'preFlush',
        );
    }

    public function preFlush  (PreFlushEventArgs  $args)
    {
        $em     = $args ->getEntityManager();
        $uow    = $em   ->getUnitOfWork();


         // get only the entities scheduled to be inserted
        $entities   =   $uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions();
        // Loop over the entities scheduled to be inserted    
        foreach ($entities as $insertedEntity) {
            if ($insertedEntity  instanceof User) {
                $mandatoryItems = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Item")->findByMandatory(true);
                // I've implemented an addItems() method to add several Item objects at once                    
                $insertedEntity->addItems($mandatoryItems);

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Create an event subscriber like explained here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'prePersist',
    );
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();

    if ($entity instanceof User) {
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        // ... find all Mandatody items and add them to User
    }
}
```

add prePersist function (if you only want on creation) check if it is the User object, get all items from the database that are mandatory and add them to User Entity.